# BrowserID without Javascript (preferably in Python) - is it possible?

Tags: python, graceful-degradation, noscript, browserid

BrowserID currently uses a Javascript shim, while browsers are still (hopefully) developing support for it. Is it possible to use BrowserID for clients that don't run javascript?

I *could* read the 600 line JS shim, and figure out what `navigator.id.getVerifiedEmail` is meant to do, then replicate it on a server, but I was hoping there's an easier way. And even then, I don't think it would really work.

OK, digging a bit deeper, this seems to be peripheral to what BrowserID is meant to do, and might require some kind custom BrowserID validator, but I'm hoping there's an easier way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Server-side" BrowserID in python or whatever is impossible by its design. Read carefully the [How BrowserID works page](http://lloyd.io/how-browserid-works), especially pay attention to section 'Certificate Provisioning' and step 3 in the flow description. It does *require* support for BrowserID and javascript from the client's browser, because BrowserID technology requires some code to be run in the client browser during Certificate Provisioning step.

Answer (score 1):

The Javascript shim exists to work around missing native support in browsers, so it will be required for the foreseeable future:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Persona/FAQ#Why_does_Persona_require_JavaScript.3F

Answer (score -1):

One solution, use OpenID or hand-rolled email verification, but then I have 2 problems. :(